# Fingerprint Reader Power Consumption

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader, powertop

I have `fingerprint-gui` working in Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo x260. The problem is that `powertop` indicates that it is constantly using about 50-100mW of power even when I am logged in and it should be off.  Has anyone found a way to put the fingerprint reader to sleep when it is not being used?

The device in my machine is the following:

```
ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
```

Comment: 100mW is basically nothing

Comment: Similar problem here with same device with ID 138a:0018. `powertop` is reporting, that it's using up to 4W (which is a 3rd of the laptop's idle consumption), while I don't even have the driver for the device installed anymore. `$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/product` -> "HP TrueVision HD". $ echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/1-1.2/power/level` -> "tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/1-1.2/power/level: invalid argument". Unbinding the device (which AFAIU should power it off): `echo '1-1.2' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` works, but `powertop` is still showing it using pwr

Comment: Similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314773/disable-a-usb-device-which-has-no-driver/314812

Answer (score 1):

strangely enough this seems to have fixed it for me:

```
echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/power/control
```

replace above with the correct USB device ID as necessary. You should be able to find the correct ID like this:

```
for p in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product; do echo -n "$p : "; cat $p; done
```